# Как доработать скрипт, чтобы отрабатывал в нескольких селектах?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код:

```js
$("#operator").change(function() {
    //alert($("#operator option:selected").text());
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "choose operator") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='0'>choose code</option>");
    }
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "Megacom") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='550'>0550</option>");
    }
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "Beeline") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='770'>0770</option>");
    }
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "Fonex") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='543'>0543</option>");
    }
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "Gorod") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='312'>0312</option>");
    }
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "0") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='700'>0700</option>");
    }
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "Katel") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='515'>0515</option>");
    }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<div id="1">
  <select id="operator">
    <option value="none">choose operator</option>
    <option value="Megacom">Megacom</option>
    <option value="Beeline">Beeline</option>
    <option value="Fonex">Fonex</option>
    <option value="Gorod">Gorod</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="Katel">Katel</option>
  </select>

  <select id="prefix"></select>
</div>

</div>
```

Отрабатывает нормально, но стоит добавить еще один `select`, то уже не работает:

```js
$("#operator").change(function() {
    //alert($("#operator option:selected").text());
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "choose operator") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='0'>choose code</option>");
    }
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "Megacom") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='550'>0550</option>");
    }
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "Beeline") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='770'>0770</option>");
    }
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "Fonex") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='543'>0543</option>");
    }
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "Gorod") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='312'>0312</option>");
    }
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "0") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='700'>0700</option>");
    }
    if ($("#operator option:selected").text() == "Katel") {
      $("#prefix").html("<option value='515'>0515</option>");
    }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<div id="1">
  <select id="operator">
    <option value="none">choose operator</option>
    <option value="Megacom">Megacom</option>
    <option value="Beeline">Beeline</option>
    <option value="Fonex">Fonex</option>
    <option value="Gorod">Gorod</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="Katel">Katel</option>
  </select>

  <select id="prefix"></select>
</div>
<div id="2">
  <select id="operator">
    <option value="none">choose operator</option>
    <option value="Megacom">Megacom</option>
    <option value="Beeline">Beeline</option>
    <option value="Fonex">Fonex</option>
    <option value="Gorod">Gorod</option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="Katel">Katel</option>
  </select>

  <select id="prefix"></select>
</div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы код работал для обоих `select`'ов?

Comment: Да, я уже сталкивался с этой проблемой. Люди, которые не имеют даже базовых познаний в HTML и JS, пытаются растащить какой-то код по кускам и что-то с ним сделать. Как решить - не знаю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить id на class:

```
<select class="operator">
```

И изменится вызов:

```
$(".operator").change(function () {});
```

И код можно существенно сократить:

```
<div id="1">
    <select class="operator">
        <option value="none" data-val="0" data-text="choose code">choose operator</option>
        <option value="Megacom" data-val="550" data-text="0550">Megacom</option>
        <option value="Beeline" data-val="770" data-text="0770">Beeline</option>
        <option value="Fonex" data-val="543" data-text="0543">Fonex</option>
        <option value="Gorod" data-val="312" data-text="0312">Gorod</option>
        <option value="0" data-val="700" data-text="0700">0</option>
        <option value="Katel" data-val="515" data-text="0515">Katel</option>
    </select>

    <select class="prefix"></select>
</div>
<div id="2">
    <select class="operator">
        <option value="none" data-val="0" data-text="choose code">choose operator</option>
        <option value="Megacom" data-val="550" data-text="0550">Megacom</option>
        <option value="Beeline" data-val="770" data-text="0770">Beeline</option>
        <option value="Fonex" data-val="543" data-text="0543">Fonex</option>
        <option value="Gorod" data-val="312" data-text="0312">Gorod</option>
        <option value="0" data-val="700" data-text="0700">0</option>
        <option value="Katel" data-val="515" data-text="0515">Katel</option>
    </select>

    <select class="prefix"></select>
</div>
```

И запуск:

```
$(function() {
    $(".operator").on("change", function() {
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected');
        var text = selected.data('text');
        var val =  selected.data('val');
        var $prefix = $(this).siblings('.prefix');
        $prefix.html("<option value='" + val + "'>" + text + "</option>");
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь все сработало.

Comment: Я внес исправления. Настоятельно советую переписать скрипт короче ;)

Comment: Внес исправления

Answer (score 1):

Согласно правилам хорошего тона, ID элементов должны быть уникальны в рамках документа. Поэтому имеет смысл `id="operator"` и `id="prefix"` заменить на `class="operator"` и `class="prefix"` соответственно.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".operator").on("change", function() {
        var text = $(this).find(':selected').text();
        var $prefix = $(this).siblings('.prefix');
        if (text == "choose operator") {
            $prefix.html("<option value='0'>choose code</option>");
        }
        else if (text == "Megacom") {
            $prefix.html("<option value='550'>0550</option>");
        }
        else if (text == "Beeline") {
            $prefix.html("<option value='770'>0770</option>");
        }
        else if (text == "Fonex") {
            $prefix.html("<option value='543'>0543</option>");
        }
        else if (text == "Gorod") {
            $prefix.html("<option value='312'>0312</option>");
        }
        else if (text == "0") {
            $prefix.html("<option value='700'>0700</option>");
        }
        else if (text == "Katel") {
            $prefix.html("<option value='515'>0515</option>");
        }
    }).change();
});
```

```html
<div id="1">
    <select class="operator">
        <option value="none">choose operator</option>
        <option value="Megacom">Megacom</option>
        <option value="Beeline">Beeline</option>
        <option value="Fonex">Fonex</option>
        <option value="Gorod">Gorod</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="Katel">Katel</option>
    </select>
    <select class="prefix"></select>
</div>
<div id="2">
    <select class="operator">
        <option value="none">choose operator</option>
        <option value="Megacom">Megacom</option>
        <option value="Beeline">Beeline</option>
        <option value="Fonex">Fonex</option>
        <option value="Gorod">Gorod</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="Katel">Katel</option>
    </select>
    <select class="prefix"></select>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Чтобы избавиться от кучи `if else`, можно использовать объект:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var map = {
        "choose operator": { value: '0', text: "choose code" },
        "Megacom": { value: '550', text: "0550" },
        "Beeline": { value: '770', text: "0770" },
        "Fonex": { value: '543', text: "0543" },
        "Gorod": { value: '312', text : "0312" },
        "0": { value: '700', text: "0700" },
        "Katel": { value: '515', text: "0515" }
    };

    $(".operator").on("change", function() {
        var text = $(this).find(':selected').text();
        var $prefix = $(this).siblings('.prefix');
        var optionData = map[text];
        $prefix.html($('<option>', optionData));
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: Вообще, автору стоило бы перенести контент из скрипта в документ, а именно в data-аттрибут и избавиться от else-if-спагетти.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev да, я уже дописываю такой вариант кода. Только из-за дублирования значений в `option` я решил оформить это через объект JS, а не через атрибуты.

Comment: Я был уверен в этом %) Можно оформить отдельным ответом, чтобы два подхода были видны.

Comment: @Regent Ключ лучше делать не по тексту, а по полю value у option.

Comment: @pavelip есть такое, но я решил оставить этот момент таким, какой он есть в авторском коде.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо, все сработало благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @Regent Это какой-то олдскул "$(document).ready(function() {"

Comment: @pavelip это не _олдскул_. Мало кто из новичков в JS/jQuery понимает, как работает `$(function() { });`, поэтому в ответах я указываю полный вариант.